# Multiple iterators for class using Iterable

Tags: java, android, iterator

Having this class

```
public class MyClass {

   private List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

   . . .
}
```

Is it possible to implement `Iterable` in the class in such a way that this code will work?:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();

for(Integer i: a) {
   <do something with i>
}

for(String s: a) {
   <do something with s>
}
```

Let me clarify that I know how to iterate in other ways, even I know that I can create an iterator for each list type, I want to know if this specific form of iteration is possible.

Comment: It is not possible. You have to chose, either Integer or String.

Comment: @kocko I see, would any of you post an answer so I can mark the question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get it working, you can implement the [java.lang.Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface and override the `Iterable#iterator()` method in the `ClassA`, but then only one of the loops will be compiling, because the iteration will be applied **only** over the one of the lists.

Better provide accessors for the lists and then do:

```
for(Integer i: a.getIntList()) {
   <do something with i>
}

for(String s: a.getStringList()) {
   <do something with s>
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you're handing over the entire list, with all the mutator methods therein. An iterator allows you to restrict operations to just iterating. C++ is much better at this...

Answer (score 1):

You can't provider a generic type with a list of bound types, so you have to decide for `String` or `Integer` - or you let `MyClass` expose the two collections through methods.